# How do I parse a string as an Integer

Tags: java

OK I have my rock,paper,scissors game working. All but the Q to quit works. Since my scanner is only taking integers, how can I pass the "Q" string to it. I would assume I just add a simple `if(string.equals("Q") {break;}` in the while loop and I'll be good to go. Let me know what you think.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{

    /**
     * (Insert a brief description that describes the purpose of this method)
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int compint;
        String usermove = "";
        String compmove = "";
        String winner = "";
        int count = 0;
        int input=0;


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random gen = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
        input=in.nextInt();
        while (count < 3)
        {
            compint = gen.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (input == 1)
            {
                usermove = "Rock";
            }
            else if (input == 2)
            {
                usermove = "Paper";
            }
            else if (input == 3)
            {
                usermove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == 1)
            {
                compmove = "Rock";
            }
            else if (compint == 2)
            {
                compmove = "Paper";
            }
            else if (compint == 3)
            {
                compmove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == input)
            {
                winner = "TIE";
            }
            else if (compint == 1 && input == 3)
            {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            }
            else if (compint == 2 && input == 1)
            {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            }
            else if (compint == 3 && input == 2)
            {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            }
            else
            {
                winner = "USER";
            }

            System.out.print("Computer: " + compmove + " | ");
            System.out.print("You: " + usermove + " | ");
            System.out.println("Winner: " + winner);
            System.out.println();
            count++;
            System.out.print("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
            input = in.nextInt();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `input=in.next()` (changing input to `String`), check to see if the `input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")`, if not, try concerting the value to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt(input)`.  This will throw a `NumberFormatException` which you should catch and remind the user to only input valid values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sandbox {

    /**
     * (Insert a brief description that describes the purpose of this method)
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int compint;
        String usermove = "";
        String compmove = "";
        String winner = "";
        int count = 0;
        String rawInput = null;
        int input = 0;


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random gen = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
        rawInput = in.next();
        if ("Q".equals(rawInput)) {
            return;     //exit main
        }
        input = Integer.parseInt(rawInput);

        while (count < 3) {
            compint = gen.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (input == 1) {
                usermove = "Rock";
            } else if (input == 2) {
                usermove = "Paper";
            } else if (input == 3) {
                usermove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == 1) {
                compmove = "Rock";
            } else if (compint == 2) {
                compmove = "Paper";
            } else if (compint == 3) {
                compmove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == input) {
                winner = "TIE";
            } else if (compint == 1 && input == 3) {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            } else if (compint == 2 && input == 1) {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            } else if (compint == 3 && input == 2) {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            } else {
                winner = "USER";
            }

            System.out.print("Computer: " + compmove + " | ");
            System.out.print("You: " + usermove + " | ");
            System.out.println("Winner: " + winner);
            System.out.println();
            count++;
            System.out.print("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
            input = in.nextInt();


        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is taking the input as a String.  I save that into a variable named `rawInput`.  Then I check if that's equal to "Q".  If it is, I quit.  If it's not, I convert it to an Integer and use the rest of your logic.

The @MadProgrammer had some good advice on how to make this code more fault tolerant which I'd follow but I posted this code because it directly answers your question.

Comment: Don't forget to change your last 'System.out' statement in the while loop to 'rawInput = in.next();
        if ("Q".equals(rawInput)) {
            return;     //exit main
        }
        input = Integer.parseInt(rawInput);'

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Either use a numerical value to quit (0 or -1), or
- Convert your program to accept both strings and numbers.  The way you do this is through [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

  ```
  // This assumes that input is of type String instead
  int option = 0;
  System.out.print("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
  input=in.nextLine();
  try {
      option = Integer.parseInt(input);
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // wasn't a number, so it was either bogus input or the quit option.
      if("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
          System.out.println("Quitting.");
          System.exit(0);
      } else {
          System.out.println("Bogus input.");
      }
  }
  while (count < 3 && option != 0) {
      // logic
  }
  ```

Comment: On second thought, it is also OK to provide feedback to user when they are not doing right, but then we need a loop on try/catch block until user enters valid input, and add in `trim()` to clean up space. Reading in line by line has an advantage to prevent weird stuff like user entering 2 numbers in a row.

Comment: @nhahtdh:  Yes.  Entering a blank is bogus input.  It's not "rock", "paper", "scissors" or "quit".  What else would it be?  Yes, I do agree that one needs an eval loop for this - it's mostly an alternative with strings.  It'd be far more straightforward to use numerical values as the "quit" option, since that's what this is engineered to use.

Comment: It is also possible to consider the blank line as user accidentally type it and ignore it. I shouldn't have put the connotation of it being bad to do so in my previous comment. I just want to point out an alternate deign with `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(myString)`

Just plug in myString

```
class JTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a = "5";
        int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

provided user doesnt input other than 0-9 and "q" or "Q" then it should work:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String a = sc.next();
   if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
       System.out.println("quit game");
   }    
   else{
       int input = Integer.parseInt(a);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your program as follows :

```
public static void main(String... args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int compint;
        String usermove = "";
        String compmove = "";
        String winner = "";
        int count = 0;
        int input = 0;
        Random gen = new Random();
        Set<Boolean> set = new HashSet<Boolean>();
        boolean contains = false;
        while (count < 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
            String nextLine=in.next().trim();
            do {
                for (int index = 0; index < nextLine.length(); index++) {
                    set.add(Character.isLetter(nextLine.charAt(index)));
                }
                contains = set.contains(true);
                if(contains) {
                if (nextLine.equals("Q")) {
                    System.out.println("program exited");
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out .print("Re-enter Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3) {Q to quit]: ");
                    nextLine=in.next();
                }
                } else {
                    input=Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
                }

                set.remove(true);
            } while (contains);

            compint = gen.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (input == 1) {
                usermove = "Rock";
            } else if (input == 2) {
                usermove = "Paper";
            } else if (input == 3) {
                usermove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == 1) {
                compmove = "Rock";
            } else if (compint == 2) {
                compmove = "Paper";
            } else if (compint == 3) {
                compmove = "Scissors";
            }

            if (compint == input) {
                winner = "TIE";
            } else if (compint == 1 && input == 3) {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            } else if (compint == 2 && input == 1) {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            } else if (compint == 3 && input == 2) {
                winner = "COMPUTER";
            } else {
                winner = "USER";
            }

            System.out.print("Computer: " + compmove + " | ");
            System.out.print("You: " + usermove + " | ");
            System.out.println("Winner: " + winner);
            System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("program's end");
    }
```